# Получение json и отправка в чат (Telegraf)

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot, telegram, telegraf

Ребят, привет всем. Начинаю изучать новую сферу и столкнулся с рядом вопросов. Так много желаний и так мало ответов)) Смотрите, как можно сделать такую тему. Допустим человек пишет в чат боту цифры (допустим 12412), далее бот сверяет наличие данных цифр в json массиве по url. Если находит такой ID то присылает весь массив но уже в нормальном виде. Пример [ссылки](https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/pubinfo?exchange&json&coursid=11) , но там не ID, а допустим если он есть. Пример массива приложу снизу. А вывод в боте в таком формате ID: 123123, Имя: Test, Дата: 28.10.2020. Дайте подсказку где можно поискать подобную реализацию или у кого то уже есть что-то. Буду благодарен за все подсказки!

```js
[
  id: "12121",
  name: "Test",
  date: "28.20.2020"
]
```

Comment: Вас интересует реализация в самом боте или как выбрать нужные данные из массива ?

Comment: @Lukas Вообще как это реализовать в плане кода в боте, чтобы получилось. Я просто не могу разобраться, на js обычном выходит, а тут нет.

Comment: Как вариант: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=245fMJNRyxs

Comment: @Lukas Это я уже давно прошёл, тут через библиотеку всё делается, а мне нужно через обычный чат всё получать.

Comment: Тогда просто создайте объект, и после каждого вопроса, наполняйте его ответами клиента. В конце работа, объект очищаете.